# Couldn't replace numbers with values in d3 js pie chart legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Am trying to replace numbers in the pie chart legend with the list of values of respective pie (Audi,Benz,BMW,Volvo etc.,)

I tried below, but it doesn't show any data in the legend

```
    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(d3.select(this).datum().data.label);
```

instead of

```
    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

Here is the **fiddle**
    http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/aovmo93x/7/

Am new to D3 JS charts, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
`d` is index to your data array

legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return data[d].label; });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot baklazan!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (without changing you code to much), will be

```
legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { 
        return data[d].label; 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aovmo93x/8/

Comment: Thanks a lot Philipp!

Answer (score 1):

It should be this way:

Adding color to your pie slice(so the label decides the color of the slice) :

```
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.label); } )
    .attr("d", arc);
```

Setting data to legend

```
var legend = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("width", r)
    .attr("height", r * 2)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data) //setting the data to legend
```

Setting the text like this to legend label:

```
legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { console.log(d);return d.label; });
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/nzncL148/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

function parameter `d` is the data bonded to the element and `i` is the data index. So can get the label as shown below.

```
legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d,i) { return data[i].label; });
```

```js
var w = 400,
   h = 400,
   r = 180,
   inner = 70,
   color = d3.scale.category20c();

 data = [{
   "label": "Audi",
   "value": 22
 }, {
   "label": "Benz",
   "value": 12
 }, {
   "label": "Volvo",
   "value": 16
 }, {
   "label": "BMW",
   "value": 6
 }, {
   "label": "Rolce Royce",
   "value": 12
 }, {
   "label": "Tesla",
   "value": 8
 }];

 var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
   return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
 });

 var vis = d3.select("#chart")
   .append("svg:svg")
   .data([data])
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h)
   .append("svg:g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + r * 1.1 + "," + r * 1.1 + ")")

 var textTop = vis.append("text")
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("class", "textTop")
   .text("TOTAL")
   .attr("y", -10),
   textBottom = vis.append("text")
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("class", "textBottom")
   .text(total.toFixed(2) + "m")
   .attr("y", 10);

 var arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .innerRadius(inner)
   .outerRadius(r);

 var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
   .innerRadius(inner + 5)
   .outerRadius(r + 5);

 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
   .value(function(d) {
     return d.value;
   });

 var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
   .data(pie)
   .enter()
   .append("svg:g")
   .attr("class", "slice")
   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
     d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(200)
       .attr("d", arcOver)

     textTop.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.label)
       .attr("y", -10);
     textBottom.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.value.toFixed(2))
       .attr("y", 10);
   })
   .on("mouseout", function(d) {
     d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(100)
       .attr("d", arc);

     textTop.text("TOTAL")
       .attr("y", -10);
     textBottom.text(total.toFixed(2) + "m");
   });

 arcs.append("svg:path")
   .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
     return color(i);
   })
   .attr("d", arc);

 var legend = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
   .attr("class", "legend")
   .attr("width", r)
   .attr("height", r * 2)
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
     return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
   });

 legend.append("rect")
   .attr("width", 18)
   .attr("height", 18)
   .style("fill", color);

 legend.append("text")
   .attr("x", 24)
   .attr("y", 9)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .text(function(d, i) {
     return data[i].label;
   });
```

```css
.slice path {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.textTop {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 12pt;
  fill: #bbb;
}
.textBottom {
  fill: #444;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
.top {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top:hover {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```